# Which variable is the result of new operator assigned to in `void isInstantiatedWithNew() {new Stack<>();}`? *(from a JUnit 5 User Guide example)*

Tags: java, new-operator, junit5

The JUnit 5 User Guide contains an example in the [Nested Tests section](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested):
Particularly, it contains the following code:

```
@DisplayName("A stack")
class TestingAStackDemo {

    Stack<Object> stack;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("is instantiated with new Stack()")
    void isInstantiatedWithNew() {
        new Stack<>();
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("when new")
    class WhenNew { 

        @BeforeEach
        void createNewStack() {
            stack = new Stack<>();
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("is empty")
        void isEmpty() {
            assertTrue(stack.isEmpty());
        }...
```

I wonder, which variable is the result of the new operator `new Stack<>()` is assigned to  in method `void isInstantiatedWithNew()`?

Comment: It's not assigned. As you see there's no assignment operator `=` anywhere and the object isn't returned from the method.

Comment: @Kayaman *Thank you!* But what is the *sense* of just calling `new Stack<>();` in `isInstantiatedWithNew()`? What implications does it have?

Comment: `isInstantiatedWithNew()` only verifies that object construction (invocation of class' no-argument constructor) occures successfully and doesn't throw any exception e.g. ArithmeticException when you perform division by zero in constructor, or something like that. I think this trivial test-case is included here just because it's a User Guide, and you don't have to do it for your own classes if you don't want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two *reasonable* explanations for that code are:

It's a typo, and it was meant to be `stack = new Stack<>();`, but this isn't a very plausible explanation.

The more reasonable one is that it tests that the no-arg constructor doesn't throw exceptions. It suits the functionality of the test, and even the name sort of suggests it.

The nested `WhenNew` depends on being able to create a `new Stack<>()` in `@BeforeEach`, so this verifies that the dependency is met before the nested tests are attempted.

Comment: Thank you. We also tried to ask the question on https://gitter.im/junit-team/junit5. Maybe some of the guys know if it was made on purpose or a bare typo.

Comment: Yes, according to JUnit developers the reason is to check the no-arg constructor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only assignment is happening in

```
    @BeforeEach
    void createNewStack() {
        stack = new Stack<>();
    }
```

Thus, only the tests in nested class `WhenNew` (or classes nested therein) can use it. Any test outside will see a variable with `null` value.

Comment: *Thank you!* But what is the *sense* of just calling `new Stack<>();` in `isInstantiatedWithNew()`? What implications does it have?

Comment: To show in the test case how an instance is created. Test as documentation.